# Batch: Unable to read file name from a variable in the for loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I have been trying to count number of line in the 1st `.txt` file generated in a folder. But `%filename%` is not being recognised inside `for` loop. It works when I `echo` it.

Any help please?

Summary - How do I read  the `%fileName%` in the `for` loop here:

```
@echo off
Title: Count number of lines in the first TXT file in a directory
cls
@Echo off
cd /D "%~dp0"
Set /a _Lines=0
FOR %%F IN (*.TXT) DO (
    set filename=%%F
    goto tests
)
:tests

::Unable to read file name in the below for loop. Hard coding works fine
For /f %%j in ('Find "_nonExists_value_intentionaly" /v /c %filename%') Do Set /a _Lines=%%j

set /A Actual_Lines = %_Lines%-2
Echo %filename% has %Actual_Lines% number of lines
```

Comment: Try `For /f %%j in ('type "%filename%" ^| Find/v /c ""') Do Set /a _Lines=%%j`, which ouputs only the number. Yours outputs `---------- filename.txt: 5`, which `set /a` can't process properly.

Comment: I would advise you change it to: `('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /C /V "" 0^<"%filename%"')` for the reasons given in the previous comment.

Comment: What's the value of variable `filename`?

Comment: Thank you Stephan, Thank you Compo.........  Your solution made my day.